# Recursively make subdirectory and move files into it with zsh

Tags: zsh

I have a bunch of files in a directory structure like this:

```
root_dir -
  - sub_dir1
    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
  - sub_dir2
    - file1.txt
    - file2.txt
  ...
```

Using `zsh`, I'm trying to make a new sub-directory named `data` in each existing directory and move the files into it.

Result should be

```
root_dir -
  - sub_dir1
    - data
      - file1.txt
      - file2.txt
  - sub_dir2
    - data
      - file1.txt
      - file2.txt
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a loop:

```
for sdir in root_dir/*; do
  mkdir $sdir/data
  mv $sdir/*(.) $sdir/data/
done
```

The slightly tricky part is ensuring you don't try to move the `data` directory into itself. In the command above, the `(.)` glob qualifier tells `zsh` to only match regular files, so only those are moved into the new directory.

If you don't mind some extraneous error messages, you can even omit the glob qualifier. Most implementations of `mv` will complain about an invalid argument (moving `data` into `data`), but will move any other files and directories passed in the argument list.